# Sitecore Login page redirecting to the login page again and again

Tags: sitecore-client, login

We are using client developer license where only one user can login into Sitecore. We are using `Sitecore 9.3`.

We are getting an issue while logging. On login page, we are giving the correct username and password but it is redirecting to login page again and again.

It is redirecting to the following URL:

> https://sc93local/sitecore/login?url=%2fsitecore%2fclient%2fApplications%2fLaunchpad%3fsc_lang%3den&returnUrl=%2Fsitecore%2Fclient%2FApplications%2FLaunchpad%3Fsc_lang%3Den

Since we are not able to login, we are also not able to check `kickuser` page as well using following URL:

https://sc93local/sitecore/shell/sitecore/client/applications/licenseoptions/kickuser

We did IIS Restart, browser cache clear, delete temporary folder to get rid of this issue but no luck.

We are seeing this issue on `Microsoft Edge` and `Chrome` but not in `Firefox`. We are able to login and see the `kickuser` page. In `Kickuser` page, we can see only once session which is for Firefox.

This is not happening for everyone in the team.

Can someone help me here.

Thanks.

Comment: what is your chrome version?

Comment: Clear local caches for users affected by this. A 302 is being cached.

Comment: already clear local chache but no luck.. @MarkCassidy

Comment: Check https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20064/how-can-i-get-sxa-login-working-with-my-federated-authentication-via-identityser - while SXA, the IdentityServer bits apply to regular websites as well

Comment: Have you checked IdentityServer for any errors?

Comment: I did not find anything in the identityserver logs. @JonKoivula

Comment: @Jitendra - were  you able to find a solution to your problem?

Comment: I did not found any particular reasion for this issue. Hence I did not find its answer so far. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Sitecore 9.3 uses Identity server for Authentication. If you've invalid Sitecore License and you've replaced it in SC instance, then you'll have to replace it in the Identity Server also.

You can also disable the Identity Server as temporary solution to see if the login works as expected by going to **App_Config\Include\Examples** and enable **Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Disabler.config**

Comment: As I said clearly, it is working fine in the FireFox.. so there is not Sitecore License issue.